# Why there is a map between $X$ and $Y$ in the definition of limit but not between them in the product definition?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Here is the definition of the product from Tom Leinster book:

> [image]

And here is the definition of the limit:

> [image]
> [image]

My question is:

What is $Du$ in case of the definition of a product? could anyone help me answer this question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no $Du$ in the case of a product because there is no $u$ (except of course the identity morphisms of $\bf I,$ but for them the triangle trivially commutes since $D$ is a functor).

The category $\bf I$ is just a pair $\{1,2\}$ and no arrow (except ${\rm id}_1$ and ${\rm id}_2$).
That way,

- a diagram $D:{\bf I}\to\mathcal A$ is just given by two objects $X=D(1),Y=D(2)\in\mathcal A,$ and
- a cone on $D$ is an object $A\in\mathcal A,$ together with two morphisms $f_1:A\to X,f_2:A\to Y$ in $\mathcal A,$ with no condition.

Comment: what does it mean for a diagram to commute trivially?

Comment: "Trivially" here meant "obviously". It is "obvious" that $f_i\circ D({\rm id}_i)=f_i$ because $D({\rm id}_i)={\rm id}_{D(i)}.$

Comment: Is $u$ in $D(u)$ a map or an object? I see your $u$ sometimes take the values $1$ or $2$ and those are objects not morphisms

Comment: @Emptymind  $u$? Where did you see any? I said there are none, except the two *morphisms* ${\rm id}_1$ and ${\rm id}_2$.

Comment: But you are writing $D(1)$ and $D(2)$, I thought that the argument u in D(u)should be a map not an object. I think I got you ..... $D$ is a functor between $2$ categories so the argument that it can take either an object or a map $u$ ...... am I right?

Comment: Yes, like in the triangle in your definition 5.1.19(a).